# Using #define to include a file in C++/g++

Tags: c++, g++

I am not trying to write:

```
#include MACRO(arg)
```

instead, I am trying to write just:

```
MACRO(arg)
```

Many people say that we cant write such macro to #include any file, but those try fails on preprocessing stage only, below one passes preprocessor but fails later, I think.

I wrote following test code tmp1.cpp (which does not compile):

```
#define HASH #
#define ZX(arg) HASH include <arg>

ZX(iostream)

int main()
{

}
```

And below is the output of some commands:

```
$ g++ -E tmp1.cpp
# 1 "tmp1.cpp"
# 1 "<built-in>"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 1 "/usr/include/stdc-predef.h" 1 3 4
# 1 "<command-line>" 2
# 1 "tmp1.cpp"



 # include <iostream>

int main()
{

}
$ g++ -E tmp1.cpp > tmp2.cpp
$ g++ tmp2.cpp
$ ./a.out
$ g++ tmp1.cpp
tmp1.cpp:1:14: error: stray ‘#’ in program
 #define HASH #
              ^
tmp1.cpp:2:17: note: in expansion of macro ‘HASH’
 #define ZX(arg) HASH include <arg>
                 ^
tmp1.cpp:4:1: note: in expansion of macro ‘ZX’
 ZX(iostream)
 ^
tmp1.cpp:2:22: error: ‘include’ does not name a type
 #define ZX(arg) HASH include <arg>
                      ^
tmp1.cpp:4:1: note: in expansion of macro ‘ZX’
 ZX(iostream)
 ^
$
```

I wonder why tmp2.cpp compiles and executes successfully but tmp1.cpp fails on compilation stage ? Isn't it that first the preprocessor is run then its output is fed to compiler ? tmp2.cpp is just preprocessed version of tmp1.cpp only.

[EDIT]

I had requirement of:

```
#ifdef SOMETHING
   #define ZX(arg)
#else
  #define HASH #
  #define ZX(arg) HASH include <arg>
#endif
```

Comment: Why are you trying to do this?  Whats wrong with `#include`?

Comment: Also, what's wrong with `#if CONDITION \ #include <file> \ #endif`?

Comment: With `tmp2.cpp`, you effectively run the preprocessor twice - once explicitly when generating `tmp2.cpp` from `tmp1.cpp`, and again implicitly when compiling `tmp2.cpp` (which also involves the preprocessing step). That's why `tmp2.cpp` compiles while `tmp1.cpp` does not - the first run manufactures a preprocessing directive that the second run then acts on.

Comment: My issue with this is that everybody knows and understands what `#include` does. But I don't know what `ZX()` and may just gloss over that without trying to understand it at first.

Comment: If you are trying to save the two seconds it takes to type `#include ` and instead make your sources *weird* to everyone else reading them, then *why*? What is the *point*?

Comment: I had requirement of:

#ifdef SOMETHING
   #define ZX(arg)
#else
  #define ZX(arg) HASH include <arg>
#endif

Comment: I always ask to the point question without pasting entire 100 lines of source code, which is difficult to read and understand

Comment: what you posted as "requirement" is an attempt for a solution. What is the real requirement? Maybe read about the [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: @Sumit "*I had requirement of ...*" - your requirement is bogus. WHY do you have this requirement? It makes no sense

Answer (score 9):

> **[cpp.rescan]/3** The resulting completely macro-replaced preprocessing token sequence is not processed as a preprocessing directive even if it resembles one...

I believe your quest is hopeless.